# prestashop file permission issues

Tags: linux, prestashop, file-permissions, prestashop-1.6

I'm facing issues accessing my website in prestashop without setting `777` file permissions. It throws `Error: 500`or `not found` error if I've not set `777` to all folder and files in `html` directory.

I then ran these 2 commands from within `/var/www/html` directory

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

After this I'm able to see my website running(only the home page), but not the admin panel or any other link. How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you checked the .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure all files and sub folders Permission changed ?
Try using following code in simple php script and run it.

Following PHP script will update all folder permission to 755 and all files with 644 permission **RECURSIVELY**.

```
<?php
exec ("find /path/to/folder -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} +");
exec ("find /path/to/folder -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} +");
?>
```

Not sure if this can help you. But you should try
**Enable error reporting in PrestaShop 1.6**

PrestaShop root folder, double click the folder named config and then open the file named defines.inc.php for editing.

Find the line of code below:

```
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);
```

Change the 'false' to 'true' and then click the Save Changes button to save and activate the change. The changed line should read as follows:

```
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);
```